# найти слова которое начинается с согласной буквы в массиве символов

Tags: c++, char, символы, ascii

```
 include <iostream>
 #include <string>
 #include <vector>
 #include <cctype>
 #include <iterator>
 using namespace std;


 int main()
 {
     int gl_i = 0;
     char ppp = 0;
     char ch[10];
     char chb[10];

     cin.getline(ch, 10);

     for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
     {
         if ((((ch[i] > 65) && (ch[i] < 90)) && ((ch[i]!=69) && (ch[i] != 73) && (ch[i] != 79) && (ch[i] != 85) && (ch[i] != 89))) || (((ch[i] > 97) && (ch[i] < 122)) && ((ch[i] != 101) && (ch[i] != 105) && (ch[i] != 111) && (ch[i] != 117) && (ch[i] != 121)))) 
         {
             for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
             {
                 if (((ch[i] > 64)&&(ch[i] < 91))||((ch[i] > 98) && (ch[i] < 123))) {
                     ch[i] = chb[gl_i];
                     gl_i++;
                 }
                 else {
                 //  chb[i] = ppp;
                     break;
                     gl_i++;
                 }

             }
         }
     }
     for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
         cout << chb[i];
     }
     return 0;
 }
```

Код сверху должен находить слова которое начинается с согласной буквы и записывать их в массив,но при попытке вызвать выводит только первый результат.
if 'ы проводят проверку на то на какой символ сейчас смотрит цикл,первый находить все гласные буквы,второй останавливает первый если будет любой другой символ кроме букв

Comment: 1. У вас результирующий массив chb, а опрашиваемый массив - ch - верно? Тогда мне (и другим) кажется, что некорректно опрашиваемый массив ch перетирать `ch[i] = chb[gl_i]` -т.к. вам не нужна "обратная связь". Писать надо всётаки в chb 2. У вас мусор в chb будет сбивать вас с толку, лучше обьявить его с нулями так `char chb[10]={0,};`, ну а дальше... чуть переделать алгоритм...

Comment: Численные значения символов  на разных машинах могут быть разными. Не используйте их для проверки символа, используйте сами символы. Создайте массив согласных букв и проверяйте  есть ли в этом массиве  первый символ слова.... Подключаете заголовочные файлы вектора и C++ строк, но не используете почему то

Comment: @ARHovsepyan латиница - на всех PC-совместимых - ланиница. это "учебное" задание, поддержка языков - да длинная тема, но тут не нужна.

Comment: `(ch[i] > 65) && (ch[i] < 90) ` еквивалентно `(ch[i] > 'A') && (ch[i] < 'Z')` что означает что две буквы не войдут в условие, А не страно, а вот Z та согласная.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string s;
    getline(cin, s);
    s += " ";

    // Гласные буквы
    string a = "aeoui";

    vector <string> words;

    string word = "";

    for(int i=0; i < (int)s.size(); i++) {
        // Если (это конец слова И размер слова не равен 0)
        if(s[i] == ' ' && word.size()) {
            // Если первая буква слова не гласная
            bool isOK = ( (int)a.find(word[0]) == -1 );

            if(isOK)
                { words.push_back(word); }

            word = "";
        }

        if(isalpha(s[i])) {
            word += s[i];
        }
    }

    // Вывести все слова
    for(auto el : words)
        cout << el << " ";

    return 0;
}
```